# Laravel Eloquent collection method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get this custom method in my Model to work:

Model:

```
public function qrCode()
    {
        $binCode = $this->code ? $this->code : 123456;
        return $this->attributes['qr_code'] = QrCode::size(200)->generate($binCode);
    }
```

Controller:

```
$AllBins = Bin::where([['id', '>=', $fromBinId], ['id', '<=', $toBinId]])->get();
$qrCodes = $AllBins->qrCode();
```

It's giving this error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::qrCode does not exist`

I've also tried `with('qrCode')` and doesn't work either.

Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try laravel `Appending Values To JSON` ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

#### Modal

```php
/**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['qr_code'];

public function getQrCodeAttribute()
{
    $binCode = $this->code ? $this->code : 123456;
    return $this->attributes['qr_code'] = QrCode::size(200)->generate($binCode);
}
```

by this `$AllBins` in this collection new key `qr_code` will be added

so you can use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) to get all `qr_code`

```php
$qrCodes = $AllBins->pluck('qr_code');
```

Comment: Wasn't necessary to use `pluck()`. Thank!